# Material-ui drawer inside a container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, drawer

How to set material-ui drawer inside a container in reactjs?

I wrapped my app page in container with 600px max width. I would like to set the drawer to start into that container not in the body page ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLp0.png)). I am using app bar position as absolute to implement on scroll events, so would not like to change it.

Here is codesandbox example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-drawer-e6vrc?file=/header.js

I found a discussion about it [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11749), but I did not figure out how to make it work in my example. From that I tried:

```js
        ModalProps={{
          container: document.getElementById("appContainerDiv"),
          style: { position: "absolute" }
        }}
```

Comment: [This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c2adpk?embed=1&file=MakeshiftDrawer.js) does not use Drawer component but might be a help

Comment: Hey! Are you looking for the drawer to appear on #d0d175 background area? How you would open and close the drawer?

Comment: @ShankarGaneshJayaraman Hi. I would like that it open in the right corner aligned with (id="appContainerDiv", my web page). In the example, it is opening based on full html page and not inside my web website (with max of 600px). Note that if the page is smaller than 600px, it presents the correct behavior. Sorry if did not get your question, and please feel free to ask more about it :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, consodering that you set `drawerPaper` with `absolute` position, I think the only thing you could do is set your style as:

```
drawerPaper: {
    minWidth: 100,
    width: "20%",
    position: "absolute",
    right: '12%',
    height: '75%',
  },
```

and the result will be:

[image]

note that this solution is not responsive!

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-drawer-forked-14whh?file=/header.js) your code modified.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Inspired on this solution,  I figure out something near with ModalProps and SlideProps to close and open the side menu. Although it worked pretty well with a little of effort the open position start in the html border resulting in bad ui behavior (I believe with more effort on slide props this can be solved) . After all I decided to change the Drawer to a 'Menu'. Thanks